# What exactly is the purpose of the embedded screw *inside* the window half with two windows

Tags: repair, windows

[image]

[image]

You see that someone bore a hole with a screw in it, the problem is that it is in the right side of the window divider (?). On the other side there is absolutely nothing, no fixation or something else. Moreover it has been sloppily embedded.

Because it is hard to see: The screw has a Philipps head.

Could someone tell me the purpose of the screw if such a purpose exists?

Comment: Can you give us a zoomed-out shot for context?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Better now?